# correct way to use class-level primitives

Tags: python

The way that class variables in Python are handled does not make any sense to me. It seems that the scope of a class variable is dependent upon its type! Primitive types are treated like instance variables, and complex types are treated like class variables:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   my_class_primitive = True
...   my_class_object = ['foo']
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.my_class_primitive, a.my_class_object
(True, ['foo'])
>>> b = A()
>>> b.my_class_primitive, b.my_class_object
(True, ['foo'])
>>> a.my_class_object.append('bar')
>>> b.my_class_primitive, b.my_class_object
(True, ['foo', 'bar'])
>>> a.my_class_primitive = False
>>> b.my_class_primitive, b.my_class_object
(True, ['foo', 'bar'])
>>> a.my_class_primitive, a.my_class_object
(False, ['foo', 'bar'])
```

Can someone please explain the following:

1. Why does this feature exist? What is the logic behind it?
2. If I want to use a primitive type (e.g. bool) as a class variable, how do I do it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "primitive" type. All types behave the same in this regard, which is to say, the type of the object has no bearing on what you describe. `a.b = ...` is simple a very different operation from `a.b.something(...)`, so it does something different. See also: [Drastically Improve Your Python: Understanding Python's Execution Model](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about primitive and complex. When you append to `a.my_class_object`, you modify the existing object. When you assign to a variable, you don't modify it. The same "problem" exists for lists if you treat them like you did the boolean:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     x = []
...
>>> i1 = Foo()
>>> i2 = Foo()
>>>
>>> i1.x = 5
>>>
>>> print(i2.x)
[]
```

When you *get* `i1.x`, Python looks at `i1.__dict__` for the attribute. If it can't find it in there, it looks in the `__dict__` of each of that object's parent classes until it does (or throws an `AttributeError`). The returned object doesn't have to be an attribute of `i1` at all.

When you *assign* to `i1.x`, you specifically assign to `i1.x`.

To modify a class attribute, refer to the class, not to an instance:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     x = 2
...
>>> i1 = Foo()
>>>
>>> Foo.x = 5
>>>
>>> print(i1.x)
5
```

Comment: Exactly. I was probably not clear enough about the cause of such behavior, but at least I was quicker ;)

Answer (score 1):

The feature exists as a form of caching for Python's class definitions.

Attributes defined in the class definition itself are considered `static` attributes of the class. e.g. they should not be modified.

I'm sure the decision was made assuming you were following best practices with respect to modifying static attributes ;)

Answer (score 1):

The proper comparison you should be making is this:

```
>>> class A(object):
    my_class_primitive = True
    my_class_object = ['foo']


>>> a = A()
>>> b = A()
>>> a.my_class_primitive = False
>>> a.my_class_object = ['bar']
>>> b.my_class_primitive, b.my_class_object
(True, ['foo'])
```

This is not what you thought you see. The "strange" behavior is caused by the concept of *mutability*. Namely, you are changing object assigned to the `my_class_object` property, while you are assigning different object to `my_class_primitive`. In first case it works for all the instances (because this is *one* object), while in the second case it works for single instance (whose property you are changing).

You are not alone in that confusion. To see another example of how mutability influences your code, you can check this: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/548696)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class A(object):
...   my_class_primitive = True
...   my_class_object = ['foo']
```

Class attributes are stored in `A.__dict__`:

```
>>> A.__dict__
>>> <dictproxy {'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>,
 '__doc__': None,
 '__module__': '__main__',
 '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>,
 'my_class_object': ['foo'],
 'my_class_primitive': True}>

>>> a = A()
>>> a.my_class_primitive, a.my_class_object
(True, ['foo'])
>>> b = A()
>>> b.my_class_primitive, b.my_class_object
(True, ['foo'])
```

The statement `a.my_class_object.append('bar')` **mutates** the list `A.my_class_object`. It retrieves the existing list, `a.my_class_object` and then calls its `append` method:

```
>>> a.my_class_object.append('bar')
```

So `b.my_class_object` is affected too:

```
>>> b.my_class_primitive, b.my_class_object
(True, ['foo', 'bar'])
```

The assignment `a.my_class_primitive = False` **add a new instance attribute** to `a`. It places a key-value pair in `a.__dict__`:

```
>>> a.my_class_primitive = False

>>> a.__dict__
>>> {'my_class_primitive': False}
```

So `b` is not affected:

```
>>> b.my_class_primitive, b.my_class_object
(True, ['foo', 'bar'])
```

[Python's attribute lookup rules](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html) cause `a.my_class_primitive` to return the value of the key found in `a.__dict__` rather than the value of the key found in `A.__dict__`:

```
>>> a.my_class_primitive, a.my_class_object
(False, ['foo', 'bar'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is not between primitives and complex types, the difference is between assignment and modifying a variable.

If you use `instance.name = value` you will always be assigning a new instance variable, even if a class attribute of the same name already exists.

For example:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   my_class_primitive = True
...   my_class_object = ['foo']
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.my_class_primitive = False
>>> a.__class__.my_class_primitive
True
>>> a.__dict__
{'my_class_primitive': False}
```

The difference in behavior here with appending to a list is because when you do an attribute lookup on a class instance it will first look for instance variables and if there is not an instance variable with that name it will look for a class attribute.  For example:

```
>>> a.my_class_object is a.__class__.my_class_object
True
```

So when you do `a.my_class_object.append(x)` you are modifying the class attribute which any instance can access.  If you were to do `a.my_class_object = x` then it would not modify the class attribute in any way, it would just create a new instance variable.